# Button click event in DataList

Tags: c#, javascript, asp.net, vb.net

I want to change the status of the button through Button click event in DataList. Please help me in this regard.

```
<asp:DataList ID="DataList1" CaptionAlign="Right" runat="server" Width="100%" Visible="true">
      <ItemTemplate>
            <table style="border-bottom:0px; border-left:0px; border-right:0px;" width="100%"  border="0" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0">                                                                            
              <tr>
                  <td width="120px"><asp:Label ID="lbl_ccode" runat="server" Text='<%#Bind("Fld_Couponcode")%>' ></asp:Label></td>
                  <td width="140px"><asp:Label ID="lbl_cval" runat="server" Text='<%#Bind("Fld_CouponValue")%>' ></asp:Label></td>
                  <td width="140px"><asp:Label ID="bl_status" runat="server" Text='<%#Bind("fld_status")%>' ></asp:Label></td>
                  <td width="140px"><asp:Button ID="btnstatus" runat="server" Text='<%#Bind("fld_status")%>' /></td>
             </tr>                                                                                                 </table>
      </ItemTemplate>
      <FooterStyle BackColor="#507CD1" Font-Bold="True" ForeColor="White" />
      <HeaderStyle BackColor="#507CD1" Font-Bold="True" HorizontalAlign="Left" ForeColor="White" />
</asp:DataList>
```

Answer (score 0):

Handle [DataGrid.ItemCommand Event](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.datagrid.itemcommand.aspx)

Occurs when any button is clicked in the DataGrid control.

```
<asp:Button ID="btnstatus" CommandName="ChangeStatus" 
runat="server" Text='<%#Bind("fld_status")%>' />

  void ItemsGrid_Command(Object sender, DataGridCommandEventArgs e)
  {

     switch(((Button)e.CommandSource).CommandName)
     {

        case "ChangeStatus":

         // Add your code here

           break;

        default:
           // Do nothing.
           break;

     }

  }
```

Comment: CommandName ="ChangeStatus"  does not work when the button is clicked.  Please help.

Comment: Private Sub ItemsGrid_Command(ByVal sender As [Object], ByVal e As DataGridCommandEventArgs)

        Select Case DirectCast(e.CommandSource, Button).CommandName

            Case "Assigned"

                Dim status1 As Button = CType(e.Item.FindControl("btnstatus"), Button)


                status1.Text = "Redeemed"


                Exit Select
            Case Else

                ' Do nothing.
                Exit Select

        End Select

    End Sub